How to iterate the sequence of pulling array items from middle (eg:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] -> 4 3 5 2 6 1 7 0) without generating the sequence number array?
For example, when pulling items from the middle of the array : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] (length is 8)


const arr=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
while(arr.length>0){
  document.write(arr.splice(arr.length/2,1)+" ");
}



the order of index of items that would pull is : 4 3 5 2 6 1 7 0
But now I want to iterate the index but not modifying the original array and without generating the sequence array (mainly due to the original array is a bit large in real code,also want an simpler algorithm), how can I iterate it with for loop only? I tried: (c=8)


for(let i=0,c=8,half=Math.floor(c/2);i<c;i++){
    document.write(half+Math.floor(i/2)+(i%2==0?1:-1)+" ");
}



which the output is 5 3 6 4 7 5 8 6 instead of 4 3 5 2 6 1 7 0, which is not working.

With i starting at 0, the corresponding sequence of Math.floor(i/2) values starts with 0, 0. You want only one 0 at the start, which you can achieve by using Math.ceil instead, for example:


for(let i=0,c=8,half=Math.floor(c/2);i<c;i++){
    document.write(half+Math.ceil(i/2)*(i%2==0?1:-1)+" ");
}



That said, do you also care about odd numbers of elements? Because that requires reversing direction:


const arr=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
while(arr.length>0){
  document.write(arr.splice(arr.length/2,1)+" ");
}

document.write("<br>");

for(let i=0,c=9,half=Math.floor(c/2);i<c;i++){
    document.write(half+Math.ceil(i/2)*(i%2==0?-1:1)+" ");
    // ----------------------------------------^^^^
}



So, in general,


function* middleOut(n) {
    let half = Math.floor(n / 2);
    let sign = n % 2 === 0 ? 1 : -1;

    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        yield half + sign * Math.ceil(i / 2);
        sign = -sign;
    }
}

console.log([...middleOut(8)].join(' '));





without generating the sequence array

That is an ideal job for a generator function. Side note: don't use document.write.


function* iterInsideOut(n) {
    if (n % 2) yield n >> 1; // When odd, yield the center value
    for (let i = n >> 1; i > 0; i--) { // Yield all other values in pairs
        yield i - 1;
        yield n - i;
    }
}

const arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90];

for (let i of iterInsideOut(arr.length)) {
    console.log(`arr[${i}] == ${arr[i]}`);
}




Here is a Ruby solution that builds the desired array by alternately removing the first (shift) and last (pop) elements of (a copy of) the given array. Each element removed is inserted at the beginning of the (initially empty) array that will be returned.
arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

a = arr.dup    
b = []
op = [:shift, :pop].cycle   
arr.size.times { b.unshift(a.send(op.next)) }    
b #=> [4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 1, 7, 0]

op is an enumerator such that
op.next #=> :shift
op.next #=> :pop
op.next #=> :shift
op.next #=> :pop
...

c = a.send(op.next) sends the method name returned by op.next to a. b.unshift(c) then inserts c at the beginning of b.
Beginning with
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b = []

we compute
c = op.next   #=> :shift
d = a.send(c) #=> 0
a             #=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b.unshift(d) 
b             #=> [0]

then
c = op.next   #=> :pop
d = a.send(c) #=> 7
a             #=> [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
b.unshift(d)   
b             #=> [7, 0]

and so on.
Demo

Find middle point by calling Math.ceil(arr.length / 2);.
Start a loop from 0 and up to this point and either add or subtract as you go along.
On the first run where your loop value is 0, skip the second value output


// Run Test, expecting: 4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 1, 7, 0
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const half = Math.ceil(arr.length / 2);
for (let i = 0; i <= half; i++) {
  console.log(half - i);
  if (i == 0 || half + i == arr.length) continue; // Skip first min where i is 0. Also skip if we are at the end of an uneven array
  console.log(half + i);
}




You can achieve this by directly calculating the indices you want to access using a loop:
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const length = arr.length;
const middleIndex = Math.floor(length / 2);
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    let index;
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        index = middleIndex - Math.floor(i / 2);
    } else {
        index = middleIndex + Math.ceil(i / 2);
    }
    document.write(arr[index] + " ");
}


You can see how it works right. You are basically finding the middle element and then going towards the beginning of the array or the end. Earlier you could do it, because the array length was shortening but now you do not have that luxury. So you have to simulate that.
You can have a direction flag, which tells the pointer where to go.
You can have a step variable, which tells how many steps to take from the center.
Since we have to handle for both odd and even length lists, there is another variable which indicates the originalDirection we had started going out with.


const arr= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
let count = arr.length;
let step = 0;
let ogDir = arr.length % 2 ? -1 : 1;
let dir = ogDir;


while(count>0){
  count--;
  document.write(arr[Math.floor(arr.length/2) + (step * dir)]+" ");
  dir*=-1; //flip the direction
  if(dir === (-ogDir) || step === 0){
    step+=1; //increase the length after every alternate iteration
  }
}



The above does exactly what you want without altering the array.

Strange, but nobody offered to use just 2 indices:


const arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

function iterate(arr, cb){
  let i = arr.length/2|0, j = i - 1;
  for(;j >= 0; i++, j--) {
    cb(arr[i]), cb(arr[j]);
  }
  i < arr.length && cb(i);
}

iterate(arr, i => console.log(i));



And don't use generators with big arrays, they are notoriously slower than usual loops.
And a benchmark:
` Chrome/124
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                     n=8        |       n=80       |       n=800       |      n=8000      
Alexander      ■ 1.00x x100m 401 | ■ 1.00x x10m 246 | ■ 1.00x   x1m 186 | ■ 1.00x x100k 186
Tushar Shahi     2.46x x100m 988 |   3.94x  x1m  97 |   4.79x   x1m 891 |   4.76x x100k 886
Ry              29.18x   x1m 117 |  39.84x  x1m 980 |  50.81x x100k 945 |  51.77x  x10k 963
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `



const $chunk = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
const $input = [], arr = $input;

// @benchmark Alexander
function iterate(arr, cb){
  let i = arr.length/2|0, j = i - 1;
  for(;j >= 0; i++, j--) {
    cb(arr[i]), cb(arr[j]);
  }
  i < arr.length && cb(i);
}
//@run
iterate(arr, i => {});

// @benchmark Ry

function* middleOut(n) {
    let half = Math.floor(n / 2);
    let sign = n % 2 === 0 ? 1 : -1;

    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        yield half + sign * Math.ceil(i / 2);
        sign = -sign;
    }
}
// @run
for (let i of middleOut(arr.length)) {
  arr[i];
}

// @benchmark Tushar Shahi
{
let count = arr.length;
let step = 0;
let ogDir = arr.length % 2 ? -1 : 1;
let dir = ogDir;

while(count>0){
  count--;
  arr[Math.floor(arr.length/2) + (step * dir)];
  dir*=-1; //flip the direction
  if(dir === (-ogDir) || step === 0){
    step+=1; //increase the length after every alternate iteration
  }
}
}
/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));




Since the logic is to fan out an array, this means we need to

Take the middle index first

In case of two indexes being the middle (even number of elements) pick one. The example has this falling on the higher of the two


Produce pairs of numbers going away from the middle indexes starting with being 1 apart from the middle and increasing this distance.


This can be done as a generator function for reusability. It takes the maximum and minimum and generates the fan out between them:


function* fanOut(max, min = 0) {
  const span = (max - min) / 2;
  const mid = Math.ceil(span) + min;
  //               ^^^^ in case of even number of items, take the higher of the middle two
  yield mid;

  for (let offset = 1; offset <= Math.ceil(span); offset++) {
    const nextLow  = mid - offset;
    const nextHigh = mid + offset;
    
    yield nextLow;
      
    if (nextLow >= min) //do not go over the maximum
      yield nextHigh;
  }
}

console.log(...fanOut(4));     // 2 1 3 0 4
console.log(...fanOut(5));     // 3 2 4 1 5 0
console.log(...fanOut(6));     // 3 2 4 1 5 0 6

console.log(...fanOut(10, 5)); // 8 7 9 6 10 5
console.log(...fanOut(11, 5)); // 8 7 9 6 10 5 11

console.log(...fanOut(5, -5)); // 0 -1 1 -2 2 -3 3 -4 4 -5 5



A small alteration is needed if in case of even number of elements, the lower needs to be picked for a middle:


function* fanOut(max, min = 0) {
  const span = (max - min) / 2;
  const mid = Math.floor(span) + min;
  //               ^^^^^ in case of even number of items, take the lower of the middle two
  yield mid;

  for (let offset = 1; offset <= Math.ceil(span); offset++) {
    const nextLow  = mid - offset;
    const nextHigh = mid + offset;
    
    if (nextLow >= min) //do not go under the minimum
      yield nextLow;
      
    yield nextHigh;
  }
}

console.log(...fanOut(4));     // 2 1 3 0 4
console.log(...fanOut(5));     // 2 1 3 0 4 5
console.log(...fanOut(6));     // 3 2 4 1 5 0 6

console.log(...fanOut(10, 5)); // 7 6 8 5 9 10
console.log(...fanOut(11, 5)); // 8 7 9 6 10 5 11

console.log(...fanOut(5, -5)); // 0 -1 1 -2 2 -3 3 -4 4 -5 5



Should the need arise, there are further changes that can be made - which number to give first (low or high), or what the step should be, etc.

With this function, generating the fan out of an array can be wrapped in a helper generator for convenience:


function* fanOut(max, min = 0) {
  const mid = Math.ceil((max - min) / 2) + min;
  yield mid;

  for (let offset = 1; (mid-offset) >= min; offset++) {
    yield mid - offset;
    if (mid+offset <= max)
      yield mid + offset;
  }
}

//for convenience to 
function* fanOutArray(arr) {
  yield* fanOut(arr.length-1);
}


const arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
for (const index of fanOutArray(arr)) {
  console.log(arr[index]);
}

/* result:
4
3
5
2
6
1
7
0
*/
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }



Or shorter using Array.from() and its callback parameter:


function* fanOut(max, min = 0) {
  const mid = Math.ceil((max - min) / 2) + min;
  yield mid;

  for (let offset = 1; (mid-offset) >= min; offset++) {
    yield mid - offset;
    if (mid+offset <= max)
      yield mid + offset;
  }
}

function* fanOutArray(arr) {
  yield* fanOut(arr.length-1);
}


const arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
const result = Array.from(fanOutArray(arr), index => arr[index]);
console.log(result.join(", ")); //result: 4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 1, 7, 0
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }



